# SQLite - executeUpdate exception not caught when database does not exist? (Java)

Tags: java, database, sqlite, exception

So I was purposely trying to break my program, and I've succeeded.

I deleted the sqlite database the program uses, while the program was running, after I already created the connection. Then I attempted to update the database as seen below.

```
Statement stmt;
try
{
    stmt = Foo.con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO "+table+" VALUES (\'" + itemToAdd + "\')");
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
}
```

The problem is, it didn't catch the exception, and continued to run as if the database was updated successfully. Meanwhile the database didn't even exist at that point since this was after I deleted it.

- Doesn't it check if the database still exists when updating?
- Do I have to check the database connection manually, every time I update to ensure that the database wasn't corrupted/deleted?
- Is this the way it is normally done, or is there a simpler/more robust approach?

Thank you.

Comment: Before further analysis, 1) I would print out Connection String and make sure it is pointing to whatever database you brought down. 2) Make sure database is really down.

Comment: What platform are you running on? Windows, Linux, Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, I found that if I delete my database when using it and then attempt to update it, it updates the database in its new location (in the trash!). You cannot permanently delete it while it is in the trash can and you are accessing it via your program.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not a SQLException that is thrown...

Try catching every Exception type and see if you get your error :

```
Statement stmt;
try
{
    stmt = Foo.con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO "+table+" VALUES (\'" + itemToAdd + "\')");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
}
```

or

```
Statement stmt;
try
{
    stmt = Foo.con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO "+table+" VALUES (\'" + itemToAdd + "\')");
}
catch(Throwable e)
{
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: I tried `Exception` and `Throwable`, and I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: Do you use a transaction ? If so, have you committed the transaction (the one that deletes the database)?